# npm install -g dredd fails on mac

Tags: ios, dredd

I need to use apiary to consume API's. Before installing dredd i have installed Node and npm.

Now when i try to execute "npm install -g dredd" 
I get following error :

```
make: *** [Release/obj.target/protagonist/src/annotation.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit         (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-        gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:88:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:173:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:201:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node"     "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/dredd/node_modules/protagonist
gyp ERR! node -v v5.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:protagonist@0.20.1 protagonist@0.20.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:protagonist@0.20.1 Exit status 1

> spawn-sync@1.0.14 postinstall     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/dredd/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall

/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)

npm ERR! code 1
```

Can anyone help regarding this ?

Comment: If `make` fails you're probably missing some (native) libraries on your system. Also, based on a [comment](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd/issues/297) in the forums, `dredd` does not yet compile on Node.js > 0.12.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately dredd is not compatible with any nodejs >= 4.0 version, but it is definitely on our roadmap.

Comment: You can follow the progress on this [github issue](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd/issues/292)

Answer (score 0):

Dredd now supports all recent versions of Node. Since version [1.4.0](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd/releases/tag/v1.4.0) Dredd also doesn't need C++ compiler or anything like that during installation. I hope you can now install it on Mac without any problems!